# Looking for second hand mobo, how do i tell if its 64 bit or 32 bit?

Tags: motherboard, 32-vs-64-bit

Im looking at this mobo but I have no clue if its 32 bit or 64 bit https://www.gigabyte.com/nz/Motherboard/GA-P67A-UD3R-B3-rev-11/sp#sp
Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: It is the CPU that determines the instruction set, not the motherboard. You should research CPUs that fit that board to get your answer.

Comment: I don't think there's any CPU left that isn't 64bit with Intel, on the consumer market. 64-bit is the norm since the Pentium D. (2005)

Comment: It uses the LGA1155 CPU Socket. All CPUs for that as per http://ark.intel.com are 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

A motherboard isn't classified as 32-bit or 64-bit, it's more about the CPU and RAM you install. The board supports up to 32GB of RAM and an i Series CPU so will support 64-bit operating systems. For Windows, anything over 4GB will require a 64-bit edition.